# Laravel: Model->save() doesn't wait on the previous model save

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to read an Excel file and inserting the records into the database. For every row I first check if the club this trainer is a member of exists, if not I create a new Club model and call the save() function.

After that I check if the trainer exists. If not, I create a new Trainer model and set the data. The club_id is obviously the same as the Club model id.

```php
for ($i = 1; $i < count($array) - 1; $i++) {
    $club = Club::find($array[$i][2]);
    if ($club == null) {
        $club = new Club();
        $club->id = $array[$i][2];
        $club->name = $array[$i][3];
        $club->save();
    }
    // $club = Club::find($club->id)->first();
    $trainer = Trainer::where('name', $array[$i][5])->first();
    if ($trainer == null) {
        $trainer = new Trainer();
    }

    $trainer->name = $array[$i][5];
    $trainer->club_id = $club->id;
    $trainer->phone = $array[$i][6];
    $trainer->email = $array[$i][8];
    $trainer->save();
}
```

Now the issue is. Whenever the club and trainer doesn't exist, I get a "Integrity constraint violation" because the 2 tables are linked by foreign keys in the database. I don't understand why, because if I simply refresh the page it will work and crash on the next item in the Excel sheet that doesn't exist in both tables.

By the comment you can see I have tried to fetch the same club from the database again, however this is inefficient and doesn't even work. I expect the code to work, because the code isn't asynchronous.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: The Laravel code works, however after a club is created in the DB it will still say that the id (foreign key) doesn't exist. If I then refresh the page and send the same data again, it will not update the club (because it exists and the data is the same) but it will now insert the trainer just fine. This makes me think this might be an issue with my database (MariaDB)

Comment: Sidenote, your syntax of `$model = Model::find()` or `$model = Model::where()->first()` can usually be replaced with `findOrNew()`, `firstOrCreate()`, etc., as documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models. Your issue might be due to setting the `id` of a new `Club` via `$club->id = $array[$i][2];`. Your `id` _should_ be auto-incrementing, so get rid of that line, and see if it works then.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will take a look at the findOrNew() function. Maybe that will solve my problem. ID can’t be auto incrementing because I’m getting the ID from an external list. I know for sure it’s unique and I need that number. By setting it as the ID I avoid a separate column

Comment: `after a club is created in the DB it will still say that the id (foreign key) doesn't exist` >>> the trick is not to save club and trainer separately, but do `$club->trainer->save();`